# Connecting to SFDC's test instance using Partner WSDL

Tags: java, salesforce, webservice-client

I created Java Proxies from partner wsdl fetched from https://login.salesforce.com/

How can I use the same proxies to connect to an SFDC account in https://test.salesforce.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on the specific client toolkit you're using, but you should be able to set the destination Url before calling login(). For Axis 1.x, you'd do

```
SoapBindingStub binding = (SoapBindingStub) new SforceServiceLocator().getSoap();
binding._setProperty(SoapBindingStub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, 
                "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/20.0");
```